# Facebook API - Permanent Access Token for pull pages info (not my own)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create a Web App that pull info about a lot of pages for some data statistics.

So, I created my Facebook App and I follow the steps for create an Access Token and all works fine: my Web App login into Facebook and pull some data.

But there is a problem: after some days I notice That my Web App do not pull anything Because my Access Token is expired.
I read into the Facebook API Docs how to create a permanent Access Token but only for my own pages.

It's possible to create a permanent Access Token for read data on other pages?

Comment: No. User access tokens are only valid up to 60 days

Comment: For publicly available data, you can use your app access token (which doesn’t expire.) But for “a lot of pages”, you might easily run into the API request limits with that. And also, you will not be able to get data about pages that are access restricted in some way.